# Export multiple actions from Blender as a single clip to Unity

Tags: animation, materials, export, actions

I created an animation with more than 200 objects that change their material multiple times using a mix shader, and two bezier curves that change their length with the **End** property.

[image]

I've been facing the follow issues:

1. When I import the .fbx file into Unity I have a clip for every change of every object.

[image]

2. ChatGPT suggested:

   *- Open the Animation window by going to Window -> Animation -> Animation.*

   *- In the Animation window, you should see the list of animation clips associated with the selected object.* **I'm not sure what list that is.**

   *- Create a new empty animation clip by clicking the "Create" button at the bottom of the Animation window. This will create a new animation clip with default parameters.* **I guess it means to create a new action in the Action Editor.**

   *- Select the first animation clip from the list and drag it onto the "CombinedAnimation" clip in the Animation window. This will add the animation data from the first clip to the combined clip.*

   *- Repeat step 6 for each additional animation clip, dragging them onto the "CombinedAnimation" clip in the Animation window. This will merge the animation data from all the clips into the combined clip.*

   *- Adjust the start and end frames of each animation within the combined clip as needed to ensure a smooth transition between the animations.*

   *- Once you have merged all the animation clips into the combined clip, you can delete the individual animation clips if desired. This is optional but can help keep your project organized.*

   *- Finally, select the objects in Unity that you want to have the combined animation clip assigned to and drag the "CombinedAnimation" clip from the Animation window onto them. This will assign the combined animation clip to the selected sphere objects.*
3. My best effort to follow this only gives one "CombinedAnimation" attached to all objects but a different animation for every curve's mesh because the actual animation of the curve is attached to its mesh.

[image]

When it comes to materials here's how the animation looks.
[image]

But there is no animation icon in the object.

[image]

My goal is to animate the visibility of two curves and the change of material of all the objects in the scene and export it to Unity.

I'm using Blender 3.2.2 and Unity 2021.3.5f1.